# GET from Glassfish with specifying .pem file

Tags: java, ssl, jersey, certificate, keystore

I am able to access the URL I want through a curl command from my Glassfish machine by specifying a cert.pem file.

In my Java application however, I tried using a jks file that holds the exact same information I get an exception.

I am doing this in Java:

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keystore_path);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "pass123");
```

Keystore path is retrieved by

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/keystore.jks").getPath()
```

While I can look inside the jks file just fine with the keytool utility, I am getting the following stacktrace from Glassfish:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java: 141) at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java: 126) at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java: 280) at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java: 382) at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java: 292) at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java: 260) at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java: 324) at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java: 229) at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java: 124) at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java: 1491) at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java: 216) at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java: 979) at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java: 914) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java: 1062) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java: 1375) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java: 1403) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java: 1387) at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java: 543) at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java: 409) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java: 177)
```

One of the suggestions is to specify to do a one-way handshake, but I'm not sure how to specify that.

Also, can I specify the .pem file as I do in the case of the working curl command and would that have any gain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the trustStore variable, not the keyStore

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keystore_path);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "pass123");
```

Ensure also that `keystore_path` points to an absolute location. It can not load files from classpath

Comment: When loading the trustStore instead of the keystore I get org.apache.hadoop.gateway.shell.HadoopException: Unable to load truststore. May be related to password setting or truststore format. I am able to access the contents of the cert with keytool -list -v -keystore store.jks (meaning I have the correct password).

Comment: Seems [Hadoop](https://github.com/apache/knox/blob/master/gateway-shell/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/gateway/shell/Hadoop.java) is using `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` too. The root cause is a IOException (look at code). May be file permissions or pointing to a bad file?  (you said the password is correct).

Comment: Pass is definetely correct, I can use keytool -list -v -keystore store.jks to check the contents of the jks. Yeap, Hadoop is also using truststore. Setting keystore property gives me this, while setting truststore gives me unable to find valid certification path. JKS file is included in the deployed war and am already using the jks file to authenticate for a Hive jdbc connection and that works fine. Completely stumped about this one...

Comment: Note that if you set a global truststore, then the default truststore at `JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` won't be used and it might affect to other applications like Hadoop. Add the required trusted certificates to your truststore. Looking at source code, seems your Hadoop was using JVM defaults, not the truststore in your classpath (if `truststoreDir`and `trustStoreFilename` are set then defaults settings are not used). See my answer `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` can not use files from classpath. You need to set an absolute location

Comment: Getting the same "has been tampered with" IOE issue when trying to import it with sudo keytool -import -keystore cacerts -file /home/xxx/store.jks. Also tried a hardcoded absolute path (although I did produce an absolute path in the first instance as well), same issue.

Comment: Could you try to load the keystore yourself to debug what it is happening? Use hadoop code: `is = new FileInputStream(file); ks.load(is, truststorePass.toCharArray());` from link